# how to run a function every time i call an object

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a Javascript framework and this is my problem: I have an object and an array. I need to clear the array every time I call the object.

```
var obj = 
{
 ary : [],
 getById :function(id){  this.ary[ary.length]= document.getElementById(id); return obj; },
 getByNames :function(names){ //loop over the names parameter and get element by names and then add these elements to the array; return obj; },
show :function(){// in here i loop over the array and show elements}

}
```

All I need to know is how to clear that array every time i recall the obj object

```
//this works perfectly 
obj.get('id').show();
//but when i recall it again like this in debugger mode i see the array have 2 elements not 1 
obj.get('another id').show();
```

All I want is to make it so that every time the obj is called to clear the array.

i need to mention it that i will have a chain in this, i mean like that

obj.getById('').getByNames('');

so i will need the array per chain then clear it in the next call of the object

regards

Answer (score 1):

If by "recall the obj object" you mean `return obj;` then just find and replace `return obj;` with `this.arr=[]; return obj;` to clear the array every time you return `obj`.

Edit:

ok so you only want to clear the array when you begin a new chain. the only way i can think of is to do something like `obj.clr().getById('').getByNames('');` and add `clr: function() {this.ary=[]; return this;}` to `obj`

Comment: you r right if there is no chaining i return obj object to use another selector so i will need what on the array for some time 
i edited my question take a look thanks for your answer

Comment: your idea is nice but cant there be something the developer dont worth clearing it him self like what in jquery

Comment: well i think i can clear the array per operation i mean something like when he call show function the array clears 

but some time some operations returns something for chaining otherwise the selectors

Comment: i don't know any way of differentiating between `obj.getById(''); obj.getByNames('');` and `obj.getById('').getByNames('');`

Comment: its just an example for chaining like jquery do getById to get for example a container and then getByNames to get elements with given names inside that container

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the function you could do `this.arr.length = 0` which will truncate the array so it doesn't have any members.

Comment: yes but i need another solution rather i will have many selectors that i will need to keep the elements on the array for some time just like 
obj.getById('').getByNames('')
for that case i will need the elements on the array for chaining

sorry for not mention that on the question :)
and thanks for your answer

Comment: so i need it per chain to be kept on the array so after chaining complete and i call the object over again i find the array clear